# a question regarding iPhone Calendar (Kal)

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, ios4, calendar, eventkit

I was wondering if Kal supports adding events? Like if I wish to support scheduling events within my app, does Kal support adding/editing events and showing it on the month view it has?

Or is it just for displaying a month view from a datasource? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Kal will show whatever you give it to show.  So if you want to show a scheduled event, just tell Kal about it....

Comment: @Dave Yes. I was wondering if the actual "scheduling" can also be done inside Kal in addition to just displaying results from an external datasource.

Comment: nope, scheduling is something you do yourself, because Kal is a *view*, which means its only purpose is to display information, not operate upon it.

Comment: +1 for confirming Kal's functionality. Thanks!

Comment: @Bourne: hello, i am also trying to add custom event on kal's calendar. I just want to add a configured game to be play on selected date along with notifications. If u can tell me how to add event on date selection along with notifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [Event Kit Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009765).